# How can I package a simple single Scala file as a stand-alone jar (no sbt)?

Tags: scala, jar, package

I have a very simple Scala file which I need to send to someone to execute on a machine without Scala (only Java).  It's just one file, with one dependency on a jar (other than scala itself).

I'm struggling to package it properly.  I'm not using sbt or anything.  What's the simplest way to package it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a file Test.scala

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    println("Hello world!")     
  }
}
```

compile it with scalac

```
scalac Test.scala
```

Create file Manifest.txt with the following content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.6.0_31 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: Test
```

Copy scala library from your distribution into the current folder and unzip it:

```
unzip scala-library.jar
```

execute the command:

```
jar cvfm Hello.jar Manifest.txt *.class library.properties scala/
```

Send it to your addressee. He/she will have to execute

```
java -cp Hello.jar
```

Comment: Super, couldn't have been simpler than that! Very much appreciated.

Comment: Spoke too soon - this of course only works if I also send them the scala-library and the your-library jars.  I'd like to make a single stand alone jar - is there no simple way to do that?

Comment: Yes, it is not possible to include a jar in another jar without redefining a classloader. Either you send scala-library with Hello.jar or include exploded scala-library.jar. See updated description.