# ClassNotFoundException:scala.PreDef$ issue

Tags: scala, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to package a simple executable Jar written in Scala, through Eclipse's Export function.

When attempting to execute the Jar from cmd `java -jar test2.jar`

I get the following error. Any ideas? Thank you.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Predef$
        at Parser.Test(Parser.scala:5)
        at Main.main(Main.java:12)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Predef$
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 12):

You just need to add the scala library jar to the classpath.

You can do it like this (assuming that the "scala-library.jar" jar is in the current directory) :

```
java -cp scala-library.jar -jar test2.jar
```

The documentation for tha `java` comamnd can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Comment: Thank you for the response. would you tell me how to do this? I am a complete newbie to Scala, Java and Eclipse.

Comment: Adding the Scala library to the classpath via Eclipse: Right-click on your project -> Build Path -> Configure Buildpath -> Libraries -> Add Library -> Select the Scala Library

Comment: Somewhy for me `java -Dscala.usejavacp=true -cp scala-library.jar -jar test2.jar` doesn't work (produces similar error message to the one specified by author), but **`java -Dscala.usejavacp=true -cp scala-library.jar:test2.jar Main` does**. Any ideas why? (I'm actually playing with dotty (not with mainline Scala) and my JAR is produced by `sbt new lampepfl/dotty.g8; cd …; sbt package` (not by Eclipse IDE's Export), but I doubt if it matters, as I anyway need scala-library.jar and it succeeds for command in bold.)

Answer (score 1):

for me i was using jdk 11 and scala library container 2.12.3 and when i changed to jdk 8 it works fine
it is because of jdk11 scala version support 
[JDK Compatibility](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html#jdk-11-compatibility-notes)

right click on the project , Build path ,configure Build path , edit your jdk to less than 11

Answer (score 0):

You can also package scala library together with your project. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16112726/1496675) post

Answer (score 0):

I did **removed** "*Scala Library container*" from project. 
Next - **add** needed scala's library (***scala-library.jar***) to *Java BuildPath* (in *Properties for* ) as "*Add External JARs...*" in **my** library (not as reference to scala lib). And innclude them all to "*Order and Export*"
**Finally** - do **Export** for project with option "*Package required libraries into generate JAR*"
and this works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute with:

```bash
scala -jar test2.jar
```

Instead of:

```bash
java -jar test2.jar
```